# isPrototypeOf in indesign

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

Hi am relativly new to indesign scripting and would like to figure out if an object is a subtype of a class. Example: I want to iterate over all page items and take everything that is not a graphic:

```
layer = app.activeDocument.layers[layerIndex];

for (i = 0; i < layer.allPageItems.length; i++) {
  alert(layer.allPageItems[i].reflect.name)
  if(layer.allPageItems[i].isPrototypeOf (Graphic) ) {
    alert("Graphic");
  } else {
    ....
  }
}
```

howver the if nver matches. Are there any examples of how to use `isPrototypeOf`? What do I have to do to test if an object is of a certain type or a subclass of it?

**edit**: To clarify, I am trying to test if I have an Instance of anything that *inherited* from Graphic.

But as far as I can see now that seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/instanceof_Operator) operator.

```
if (layer.allPageItems[i] instanceof Graphic) {
    alert("Graphic");
} else {
    ....
}
```

You could also use `isPrototypeOf` but you have to reverse the order and get the prototype itself, not the constructor. So it would look like this:

```
if (Graphic.prototype.isPrototypeOf(layer.allPageItems[i])) {
    alert("Graphic");
} else {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Both methods wont work for suptypes of Graphic, like e.g. Image. I have to test for Image directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can get access to the essence of the pageItem by calling the getElements() method. It returns an array of the original material.
Given a rectangle on a page (nothing else) :

```
app.activeDocument.allPageItems[0].getElements()[0] instanceof Rectangle //true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure its not supposed to be

```
Graphic.isPrototypeOf(layer.allPageItems[i])
```

or something like

```
Graphic.prototype.isPrototypeOf(layer.allPageItems[i])
```

?

Your current version sounds like its backwards.

Comment: i have no clue how to use it thats why I am asking

Comment: If you have no idea how to use it how do you even know it exists?

Comment: you know adobe delviers a documentation, unfortunately it lacks examples (I know there come a few with indesign,...)

Comment: The later version is correct, however it won't tell me true if the item tested is a subtype of graphic.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is not possible, I also asked on the adobe Forums with this result:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/4461211#4461211

So the short answer is, I have no way to check if I hold an object wich is an instace of `someClass` or a child thereof. Neither reflection nor `isPrototypeOf` help.

I might try casting in a try catch block but consider this as ugly. Thus I will go with the solution suggested on the adobe Forums, test for all possible heirs (children/classes inherting from base) and the base class. This is ugly and lengthy but I have not found a better solution.

**edit**: here is an exceprt from one of adobes examples, it allows for the switch syntax avoidng an endless if construct:

```
switch (app.selection[myCounter].constructor.name){
    case "Rectangle":
    case "Oval":
    case "Polygon":
    case "GraphicLine":
    case "TextFrame":
        myObjectList.push(app.selection[myCounter]);
        break;
}
```